# Aliasing the rm command to avoid evaluating separate asterisks

Tags: bash, shell, alias, rm

I would like to use the `rm` command such that it returns an error when there is a separate asterisk in its argument. For example, if I type `rm -f * .txt` , then this command should not be executed (this way I have already removed several files unintentionally). Could you please help me what the simplest way is to do this?

Comment: This is not possible (or at least not *useful*) because it is the shell in which you run such a command that expands the `*`.  The `rm` command never sees it, and therefore cannot provide any special handling for it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is it also not possible to write a user-defined command which parses the argument of `rm`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger What do you mean by *not useful*'? What can be more useful than preserving a file which you do not want to remove?

Comment: I mean "not useful" as an alternative characterization of the situation I describe afterward.  It does not matter if your alternative `rm` command is programmed to return an error if it sees a bare `*` among its arguments, because it will see that only when it means a file literally named "\*".  Again, and in response also to your other comment, it is *the shell* that expands the `*`.  You could conceivably write a custom shell that has behavior such as you describe, but the behavior you want to change does not belong to `rm`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Then what do you suggest to avoid such a situation?

Comment: The conventional approach is to be careful when running `rm` commands, and especially `rm` commands involving wildcards.  Also, note well that occasionally, `rm *` is exactly what you want.  Not that delivering unwelcome news places any onus on me to have any such suggestion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But you never want to remove additional files beyond everything... So `rm *` makes sense, but `rm * .txt` doesn't.

Comment: Some folks, use an alias like `alias rm='rm -i'` , which some folks also say that it is a bad practice, but IMHO it is a better alternative than what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't want to be careful, just keep my important files.

Comment: And with that, I think we have reached the [DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) level.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes, and confirm the deletion of 13523246846 files one by one... Quite realistic.

Comment: It seems that Super User provides a solution to this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/864478/prevent-user-typing-accidental-space-between-rm-and-wildcard.

Comment: `rm * .txt` certainly _does_ have a useful meaning. The `*` expands to all non-hidden files, the `.txt` is one specific hidden file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, there is normally no way for an `rm` alias or function to detect if it was run with a `*` that was expanded by the shell to a list of arguments.  This Bash function demonstrates a possible alternative way to help with your problem:

```
function rm
{
    local arg
    for arg in "$@"; do
        if [[ $arg != -* && ! -L $arg && ! -e $arg ]]; then
            printf 'rm: ERROR: argument does not exist: %q\n' "$arg" >&2
            printf '    Nothing is being removed\n' >&2
            return 1
        fi
    done

    command rm "$@"
}
```

- The function checks all of its arguments.  It prints an error message and returns immediately with non-zero status if any of them isn't an option, isn't a symlink, and isn't an ordinary file, directory, or special file.  The explicit check for a symlink is necessary because a symlink to a non-existing path fails the `-e` test.  For instance, if run with `rm * .txt` it will delete nothing because it will detect a non-existing `.txt` file.
- If none of the arguments fails the checks, it runs the real `rm` on the full list of arguments.